# User profile in Angular2 getting wrong user

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm still learning Angular and now I'm having a problem creating an user profile component. When I go to the user profile it displays all the data I want. The only detail is that is showing the data from another user and not the current user. As you can see is a big detail, so I'll be very grateful if you can help me with this problem. This is my code:

Component.ts

```
public user$: Observable<User>;
private email: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.route.params
      .switchMap(params => this.userService.findUserByEmail(params['email']));
```

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionsService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  findUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.af.list('users', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'email',
        equalTo: email
      }
    }).map(res => User.fromArray(res[0]))
      .do(user => console.log('user: ', user));
  }
```

Comment: The implementation looks okay. I think you need to include the route and the database data, too.

Comment: I agree with @cartant, if you are seeing data on the page, but it's the wrong data, then perhaps your problem is in your query or your data.  Look for duplicate emails, or bad email parameter.

Comment: I dont know whats going on. Even if I have just 3 users in my database, most of the time it displays the wrong user data